# Annotations for NULL Dereference in Prefast and Compiling on GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, static-analysis, prefast

I have the following example code and would like to know what kind of annotations I can use to avoid them.

```
int Function(classA* pInput) {
   if (pInput == NULL) {
      classA::Create(pInput);
   }

   return pInput->value;
}
```

The problem is that since Prefast evaluates only the function it doesn't know that `Create` initializes the pointer.

I thought I could solve it by using the `__out` annotation in the header file for `classA::Create` however that didn't work.

I'm wondering if there is a good alternative to just `__analysis_assume` everywhere in the code such that prefast picks it up from the function definition.

Secondly,
I was wondering how would I set up my build configuration so that I can build my code natively on Linux or with GCC with these preprocessor directives. Would I have to check if it's on a LINUX build and then add those annotations as empty Macros?

Comment: I've seen this indentation style a _lot_ over the past week or so. Is it from some textbook?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code assuming `Create` is a static method that actually allocates and initialize the object. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I'd like to forward a motion to burn this indentation style with fire.

Comment: Seconded, although I don't Tom's edit either. I'm one of those horrible ones who puts brackets on their own line with proper spacing of code so it's easy to see each scope block.

Comment: It triggers the following warning: 6011 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff539809(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The reason being is that prefast has no way to know that Create is guaranteeing to initialize the pointer?

Comment: What is the signature of `classA::Create` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSalter’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489255/annotations-for-null-dereference-in-prefast-and-compiling-on-gcc/7490614#7490614) sounds very much like the correct technical answer. Happily I don't know SAL so I can't say for sure, but it looks like the technical level solution.

However, I would just recommend that you rewrite your current code …

```
int Function(classA* pInput) {
   if (pInput == NULL) {
      classA::Create(pInput);
   }

   return pInput->value;
}
```

as …

```
int Function( classA* pInput ) {
   if (pInput == NULL) {
      pInput = classA::Create();
   }

   return pInput->value;
}
```

The main issue here is whether you're **leaking** a dynamically created object, or not. That depends very much on what the `Create` method does. But it does look like you're leaking.

And in that case, where `Create` does nothing but dynamically allocate a default-initialized `classA`  object, then here is how you can do that more safely *and* more efficiently:

```
int Function( classA* pInput ) {
   if (pInput == NULL) {
      return classA().value;
   }

   return pInput->value;
}
```

Finally, for a total clean-up consider how to get rid of unnecessary raw pointers. Because raw pointers create problems (your code being just a very small example of that). Then you can do things like this:

```
int function( ClassA const& anObject = ClassA() )
{
   return anObject.value;
}
```

Essentially this is a C++ level solution, as opposed to the original code's C level. So I changed also the naming convention to reflect the much stronger focus on types at the C++ level. Here the types have uppercase first letter, and a mere function has lowercase first letter.

It's simpler, it's safer, it's again more efficient.

And – at the C++ level you generally don't have to struggle with silly SAL notations. :-)

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: +1 for the leak detection, +1 for suggesting to use a reference rather than a pointer, -1 for not suggesting to throw an exception in the case of a null pointer. Net: +1.

Comment: @David: I chose to treat the code as intentional, and in that case a nullpointer is not an error but the designed way to get a default. Now gimme the extra upvote!

Comment: I tried but I got this message: "*You last voted on this answer 1 hour ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.*"

Answer (score 1):

Seems like SA is missing `[Post( Null=No )]` on the `classA*&` parameter of `classA::Create(classA*)`

Comment: I cannot simply add __out to ::Create?

Comment: I don't think so. `__out` merely guarantees that `pInput` has _a_ value, not that it has a non-null value. Note that `[]` is [the new syntax](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/19/602077.aspx)